# how to get MAC address of phone with phonegap?

Tags: cordova, mac-address

Is it possible for me to obtain the MAC address of android and iphones via phonegap javascript?

How would I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should consider using `device.uuid`, which returns an Universally Unique Identifier. It's probably the best way to uniquely identify a device and it works on almost any platform. Consult the [PhoneGap API Docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.3.0/phonegap_device_device.md.html#device.uuid) for more information.

**Update**: It seems that this solution no longer works under iOS5+.

Comment: does the android uuid guarantee to be unique? It seems to be just a random number

Comment: According to the comments in the example in [the docs](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.3.0/phonegap_device_device.md.html#device.uuid) it's a random 64-bit integer that is generated on the device's first boot. So it's unique!

Answer (score 2):

Yes as stated above the solution no longer works as desired. Though unique, the ID will change with each re-install of your app. What I was looking for was a way I could have a single constant unique identifier for the life of my app on the user device, regardless if they uninstall/install at least the ID will always be the same for that user. I found a secure solution here.

https://github.com/blackpixel/BPXLUUIDHandler

I ended up looking at the wizUtils plugin and with the help of a friend actually made it so I could use it as an actual plugin in phone-gap using it like one of the prebuilt wizUtils methods and it works!

**Update 06/13/2019**

For those using ionic4 check out (does the same thing)

https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/unique-device-id

Comment: btw this is the "real" working solution...the mac address is just the simple way to do it. As you know the MAC address of any device can be spoofed especially if the device is rooted/jailbroken. I suggest for consistency use BPXLUUIDHandler. If you look up how to write phone gap plugin you can do it. I was too lazy to do all that so I added to an existing plugin called wiztools :} if anyone needs help let me know.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/mohamed-salah/MacAddress/tree/6869bad83906a760cb81bdc5e3c349e197cd215d

will work in 2.5.0, 2.7.0, 2.9.0, 3.0.0, 3.1.0, 3.2.0, 3.3.0

Comment: It doesn't work on iOS 7, it returns 02:00:00:00:00:00. Getting the MAC address isn't possible on iOS 7, not a phonegap problem

Answer (score 1):

As Eskim0 pointed out, `device.uuid` won't return a persistent unique identifier because of changes to iOS. If the user uninstalls the app you will get a brand new identifier.

For most people trying to uniquely identify the device, the ID must be the same whether the app is uninstalled or not.

My thought were to get the MAC address sha256 with a nice salt on `deviceReady` and see if it exists in my database.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in the API that would support this.  Assuming you could get this information from Android or the iPhone, you'll need to write your own plugin to do it.